# Cómo procesar correctamente estos ficheros externos en TXT?

Tags: archivo

estoy con un pequeño programa que tiene que leer los números (sin la letra) de una serie de DNI de un archivo txt y ponerlos con su letra correspondiente en otro archivo txt, hay números que no tienen los 8 dígitos, e incluso negativos, esos números el programa no los tiene que tener en cuenta, mi forma de actuar es el de convertir el string en lista para así poder manipularlos mejor, para después discriminar los negativos y los menores de 8 dígitos y mediante una instrucción que imprima la unión del número y la letra,(algo como letra[num%23]). De momento llevo esto

```
fichero_a=open('dni5_7.txt','r')
letra='TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE'
count=0
lista=[]
for numero in fichero_a:
    lista.append(numero)

print lista
```

Me da una lista pero con saltos de línea, mi pregunta es como poder eliminarlos. Pongo la lista resultante.

```
['29042806 29237340 29345675\n', '41894345\n', '2934556 2934589\n', '41789456\n']
```

Comment: Esto es... python? Procura indicar en las etiquetas el lenguaje en el que escribes tu código para que puedas recibir ayuda oportuna. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: OK, sí, es python, cambio la etiqueta no tengo el día centrado

Comment: debes colocar un ejemplo de la data de entrada y el resultado esperado.